# Assign External Database Queries to Global Variables and Make Them Accessible

Tags: custom-post-types, php, mysql, globals

I've got a bit of a tough question involving a `website` and its `web app` counterpart.

## The Background

The ***website*** relies on **two** different databases: its default, named **`wp_website`**, and its counterpart's (aka the `web app`), named `wp_webapp`.

Again, the **website** is powered by `wp_website`.

The **web app** is powered by `wp_webapp`.

I've successfully been able to connect the two databases together. I am able to query the `wp_webapp` database from my `wp_website` installation.

## The Setup

I've created a custom `post_type` called `franchise`. The template I'm using for each `franchise` post is contained within a directory **named after its parental `post_type`**.

The file directory looks like this:

```
my-theme
|-- content-single-franchise.php
|-- single-franchise.php
|-- single-franchise
    |--- history.php
    |--- location.php
    |--- name.php
    |--- photo.php
```

Rather than import all of the `wp_webapp` data into `wp_website`, I've decided to generate the `franchise` posts on-the-fly using `get_query_var` and the `wp_webapp.franchise_id` integer value.

The URL to view any franchise looks like this: `www.acmeinc.com/franchise/<wp_webapp.franchise_id>/`.

## The Queries

In my non-publicly-accessible `franchise-queries.php` file is where my external connection settings and all external queries are written. I've stored them all to my `FranchiseDatabase` class.

The instance of the `FranchiseDatabase` class is stored to the `$franchiseRecords` variable also contained within the `franchise-queries.php` file. I then define `$franchiseRecords` inside `wp-config.php` so that it is globally accessible.

## The File Contents

### `single-franchise.php`

Inside my `single-franchise.php` file, I've declared

```
$franchise_id = get_query_var( 'franchise_id', false );
```

Within that same file, I call `get_template_part( 'content', 'single-franchise' );`

### `content-single-franchise.php`

The overall template is generated using custom `hooks`:

```
global $franchise_id, $franchiseRecords; // My first call to `$franchiseRecords`

// `var_dump( $franchiseStats )` confirms data from wp_webapp is being pulled
$franchiseStats = $franchiseRecords->get_franchise_stats( $franchise_id );

do_action( 'fran_location_name' ); // Loads single-franchise/name.php

do_action( 'fran_before_image' ); // Opening <div class="photo"> element

    do_action( 'fran_single_image' ); // Loads single-franchise/photo.php

do_action( 'fran_after_image' ); // Closing </div> for div.photo

do_action( 'fran_location_map' ); // Loads single-franchise/location.php

do_action( 'fran_location_history' ); // Loads single-franchise/history.php
```

### The Issue

#### `single-franchise/photo.php`

Beginning in the `photo.php` file, I declare `global $franchiseStats`. However, when running `var_dump( $franchiseStats )` it returns `NULL` and/or empty.

My question is **why is it returning `NULL` when I've just defined it within content-single-franchise.php?**

I know I could just run `$franchiseStats = $franchiseRecords->get_franchise_stats( $franchise_id );` but wouldn't that be redundant?

Any advice would be much appreciated.  Cheers!

Comment: declare `global $franchiseStats` in `content-single-franchise.php` as well.

Comment: just do not use globals, and you will avoid worrying about all the execution paths you didn't think of.